# PHP MySQL Select MAX() from Group of Results

Tags: php, mysql

I have one MySQL query I'm struggling with and I just can't seem to make it work.

Here's what it looks like:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT reminders.recordID 
FROM 
    reminders, 
    (SELECT 
        DISTINCT recordID, 
        MAX(date) as MaxDate 
     FROM reminders 
     GROUP BY recordID
    ) dts 
WHERE 
    reminders.owner = '$owner'
    AND reminders.date = dts.MaxDate
```

I need to get all reminders in the table (reminders) for, say, `recordID` 14. Then I need to select the most recent date (`MAX()`) from that set of results and return the `recordID` with the most recent date BUT not beyond a certain date (`WHERE date <= '$date'`).

Anybody have any ideas on how I might go about this?

Answer (score 1):

How about ...

```
SELECT recordID, date
FROM reminders
WHERE owner = $owner
AND date <= $date
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

... oh, I think I see now: "Each ID may have a couple reminders attached to it" clears something up. So there's probably a much more elegant solution to this, but I'm guessing this will work:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT r1.recordID,
        (SELECT r2.date
            FROM reminders as r2
            WHERE r2.owner = $owner
            AND r2.date <= $date
            AND r2.recordID = r1.recordID
            ORDER BY r2.date DESC
            LIMIT 1) as maxDate
    FROM reminders as r1
    WHERE r1.owner = $owner
    AND r1.date <= $date
```

Comment: you forgot AND recordID = '$recordid'

Comment: i couldn't quite make out from the description if that part was necessary :) ... like why would he have "SELECT DISTINCT reminders.recordID" if it was already know?

Comment: True, I assumed it was necessary because OP stated 'for, say, recordID 14', but to be honest it wasn't in the example query.  We'll file it under "We're both right"?

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Sorry for not being clear in my original post.
What I'm looking to get is an array of all the recordIDs that belong to "$owner" and the most recent 'reminder' for that record. So if record, say, 14, had a reminder on 7/21, 7/22, 7/27, 7/28 and 8/10, I'd like to get an array like this: array("recordID"=>14, "date"=>'7/28') but for each record that belongs to '$owner'....could be a couple records or it could be over 100. Does this make more sense?

Comment: The above could will do that if you remove "LIMIT 1", and then the date records will be in descending order (most "recent" first).

Comment: But I'm guessing I don't yet understand what you want, because you probably would not have used MAX unless you needed something else. What am I not seeing?

Comment: The dates are in this format: "2011-07-28" so I'm using MAX to get the latest date...it picks up that "2011-7-22" is less than "2011-07-28" and will not select it.

Comment: I now have this which does exactly what I want it to do except it still includes dates that are greater than '$date'. When I just tested it, it was returning reminders for 2011-08-15 even though '$date' was set to today's date (2011-07-29). 
"SELECT tbl1.date as newDate, tbl1.id as newID FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date, MAX(date) as maxDate, recordID AS id FROM reminders WHERE owner='$owner' AND date <= '$date' GROUP BY recordID) AS tbl1 WHERE tbl1.maxDate <= '$date'"
Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want to post some sample data and a sample of the result you'd like to see, I might be able to help. Otherwise, I'm still not getting what you're doing here :)

Comment: Each 'recordID' is like a group of reminders. Each ID may have a couple reminders attached to it. What I need to do is select the recordID and the most current date (like 2011-07-29 instead of 2011-07-25) for every recordID that has an owner equal to '$owner' and is less than some other defined date ('$date'). But I need it to return an array of those. Here's some sample data that I want returned.
I'll add some sample return data in my next comment.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [maxDate] => 2011-07-20
            [recordID] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [maxDate] => 2011-07-25
            [recordID] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [maxDate] => 2011-07-25
            [recordID] => 51
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [maxDate] => 2011-07-20
            [recordID] => 53
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [maxDate] => 2011-07-18
            [recordID] => 54
        )
)

Comment: @neokio - That's it. That brought me what I wanted. Thank you so much! Although is there a way to reference the 'column' you created called 'maxDate' anywhere else in the statement? I'd like to change the bit at the end that says AND r1.date <= $date to be "AND maxDate <= $date" so I only return an array with items who's maxDate is less than or equal to $date. I've played with it a bit but can't seem to get it. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I got it this way but I'm not sure it's the most efficient or best way of doing this. I basically copied your statement (r2) to the bottom line so it's in there twice now. 
 AND (SELECT MAX(r2.date) FROM reminders as r2 WHERE r2.owner = '$owner' AND r2.recordID = r1.recordID ORDER BY r2.date DESC LIMIT 1) <= '$date'